# jQuery form validation - Login

Tags: jquery, html

I've tried to made it to be "jQuery form validation," but I can not really get it to work. It does not come up with some errors at all.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            adgangskode: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Html/form here:

```
<form name="login" action="#" method="post" id="login">
                <p>Brugernavn</p>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="loginbar">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="adgangskode" class="loginbar">
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log ind" class="click login">
            </form>
```

problem: it does not appear and show some error or say "**hey you are missing is a password**."

**EIDT**

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#login').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        adgangskode: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    }
});
});
```

Html

```
<form name="login" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" id="login">
            <p>Brugernavn</p>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="loginbar">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" id="adgangskode" name="adgangskode" class="loginbar">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log ind" class="click login">
        </form>
```

Comment: Set id for your inputs as same as the key you used in your rules. for example `id="adgangskode"`

Comment: @Mohebifar What you mean??, Mean you #adgangskode?

Comment: He means like this: `<input type="password" id="adgangskode" name="adgangskode" class="loginbar">`

Comment: @andre3wap I add how the code looks now up to the top, but it does still not :(

Comment: can I see the page where you have the code ? if none of the suggestions work.

Comment: @andre3wap you can show its problem her: http://billedeupload.dk/?v=mrBG.png

Comment: Have you made proper linking to these files in your header ? jquery.js
and validate.js

Comment: @andre3wap What you mean??

Comment: in your page header, do you have `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` or something similar (CDN), linking to the jquery and validate.js library

Answer (score 0):

`$("#form")` looks for `<form id="form"...`
`$(".form")` looks for `<form class="form"...`
`$("form[name=form]")` looks for `<form name="form"...`

Also check you have included all the necessary files in the correct order:

- jquery.js
- validate.js
- additional-methods.js
- Then your custom JS...